# Kartik datepicker календарь не пропадает при выборе даты на Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, datepicker

При выборе даты, дата корректно попадает в поле ввода. Однако сам календарь несмотря на то, что дата уже была выбрана, не исчезает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_complete')->widget(DatePicker::classname([

        'options' => [
            'style' => 'width: 40%;',
        ],

        'pluginOptions' => [
            'language' => 'ru',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'format' => 'd.m.y',
            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_BUTTON,
        ],

    ]
));


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно дописать 'autoclose' => true в pluginOptions

Comment: До этого добавлял, никакого результата

Comment: ctrl+f5 делали? http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker тут много примеров

Comment: Да, конечно. Даже через yii cache/flush-all чистил

Comment: Попробуйте открыть исходный код в браузере на странице с DatePicker`ром и посткать там autoclose. Если не найдете типа такого jQuery('#someid..').....datepicker({"clearBtn":true,"toggleActive":true,"autoclose":true," .... значит параметр не попадает в яваскрипт и надо смотреть там ли вы его добавляете

Answer (score 0):

в assets `vendor/katrik/date` в файле `bootstrap-datepicker.js` надо найти параметр `autoclose` и там прописать `true`, у меня после этого исправилась

Answer (score -1):

```php
'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
]
```